# problema al retornar a una web con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un select con options en el cual marco el option (selected) segun la url (PHP)

ahora bien, yo estando en *inicio* y me voy a *nosotros* funciona perfectamente porque mi select me marca el option con el value "nosotros" pero si retrocedo (pc) o doy atras (celular) me retorna a la pagina anterior (*inicio*) pero el select me lo sigue marcando como "nosotros" a pesar de estar en *inicio*

Nota: cuando cambian el select detecto el change y segun el value del option seleccionado los dirijo a la pagina correspondiente

esto es un problema porque por ejemplo estando en inicio me sigue marcando que estamos en nosotros y si deseo ir a nosotros no podria porque el select no me llama al evento change ya que no se cambio nada.

Comment: Amigo agrega imágenes o código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: desactivar el autocompletado del select https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion o poner un script onload que lo setee `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { // código });`